# Use quotation marks for phrases on items

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I am editing a story with a character who is wearing a "Search and Rescue" T-shirt. If I understand correctly, "Search and Rescue" is not a proper name. The shirt simply identifies the character as a member of the Search and Rescue team. So, in this context, how would the phrase "Search and Rescue T-shirt" be punctuated?

Would it be any different if the shirt had a name (as in a "Metallica T-shirt"), or if the shirt had a phrase (such as a "Keep Calm and Carry On T-shirt")?

Comment: Are there other members of the team in the story or is one person in the story wearing the emblematic shirt?

Comment: There are other members of the team in the story, but this character is the only one described as wearing the shirt.

Answer (score 1):

If the quotes are actually being used *correctly*, they mean that the shirt literally reads "Search and Rescue".

Like this one:

[image: Search and Rescue Shirt]

Though, technically, the above shirt would be a "SEARCH AND RESCUE" shirt.

So, if the person was wearing a shirt like this:

[image: Metallica shirt]

Then it would be a "Metallica" shirt.

Same is true with "Keep Calm and Carry On" t-shirt.

The quotes imply that that is what the text on the shirt reads, so you shouldn't use the quotes around the word "t-shirt".